# Using times at asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i am trying to build a `timer` in my asp.net website.

so, when you click on a button, lets say hes id = `"Button1."` it will make the `button disable`(with `enable = false` command) and after few\4secconds it will enable=true again.

i have tired to look around how to to so, but all guilds online are very old.. and nothing is realyl helpfull.

This is the full code name(just for the exple):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Thanks alot! please help me :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following answer it should be what you are after:

[Disable an asp.net dynamic button click event during postback and enable it afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153586/disable-an-asp-net-dynamic-button-click-event-during-postback-and-enable-it-afte)

Answer (score 0):

you cant do that in the server side. youll have to do it in client with setTimeout Js function with 4000 ms.

you have to understand that when you see the page - ther server doesnt know the page anymore. and he cant post back by himself.

Comment: Can you give me an explne of how i do it? dont forgot i am using "runt server" on my buttons.. so need to use findbyclass.

Comment: no prob - you can give the buttons cssClass and it will be generated as is ( or you can use ClientId server side function if you want to find via ID). `$(".btn1").click (function (){$(this).attr('disabled','disabled'); setTimeout($(".btn1").removeAttr('disabled'), 4000);});`